# Bootstrap 4: How can I change the color of checkbox ? Simple way

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: I Want to change that blue to green]

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
    <label class="checkbox-inline pull-left" for="rme"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox checkbox-primary" id="rme"> Remember me</label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Login">
</div>
```

How To modify same code to make the checkbox background color to be green

Comment: You might want to get out of default browser components for doing such customizations, take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: Thanks, Man & I will check this  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are already using Bootstrap's "custom" form controls (albeit slightly incorrectly -- the markup for custom Bootstrap 4 controls is different from your example).

Here's the correct markup for a custom checkbox in Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

The custom look is governed by the `custom-*` CSS classes. As you are seeing, the default color is Bootstrap's primary "blue" color. To make it green, you would have to override or add your own custom CSS class(es). Here is an example that uses a new class so that if you still want to use the default blue sometimes, you can.

```css
.custom-control-input-green:focus~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: #28a745 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.25) !important;
}

.custom-control-input-green:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: #28a745 !important;
  background-color: #28a745 !important;
}

.custom-control-input-green:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: #5bd778 !important;
}

.custom-control-input-green:not(:disabled):active~.custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: #d6f5dd !important;
  border-color: #d6f5dd !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-green">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input custom-control-input-green" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Saoud, have you checked [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) on W3Schools?

You have many options to do this. Also, some frameworks have their own styles for checkboxes.

Examples:

- [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html)
- [Foundation Switch Buttons](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/switch.html)
- [UIKit Custom Controls](https://getuikit.com/docs/form#custom-controls)

Mainly what you do in these cases is override the default behavior and appearance of checkboxes and use images or colors.

Comment: Thanks, Mihail, I am still learning and I want to use Bootstrap so I will check W3schools first, also I've tried many ways to override that with no hope, Just a question can I use some materialize with the bootstrap project?

Comment: Hmm, it's not a good idea to mix front-end frameworks, you'll probably get conflicts with styles. What you could do is replicate the checkbox structure and copy and modify the styles. Normally when they are customized they used some additional html in the form of a span that changes depending on the input's checked status.

Answer (score 0):

add accent-color to the class

```
.custom-checkbox {
color: green;
accent-color: currentcolor;
}
```

Comment: When submitting code, please adjust your code so that it addresses the question directly. There is no `checkbox_color` class anywhere in the OP's code.

Comment: Please add to your answer to explain how to use your proposed solution.